# how to create a necessary folder according to the seed data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to create the folder with the seed data, using ASP.NET CORE 5.0.

I have the DB context setup as follows:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
          : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Artist>().HasData(
              new Artist
              {
                  Id = 1,
                  Name = "Jiddu Krishnamurti"
              }
            );
        modelBuilder.Entity<Album>().HasData(
            new Album { Id = 1, DisplayName = "freedm-from-the-known", ArtistId = 1, Name = "Freedom from the Known" },
            new Album { Id = 2, DisplayName = "twelve-conversations", ArtistId = 1, Name = "Twelve Conversations David Bohm (Brockwood Park UK and Gstaad Switzerland 1975)" },
            new Album { Id = 3, DisplayName = "can-there-be-complete-freedom-of-thought", ArtistId = 1, Name = "Can There Be Complete Freedom of Thought? (Public Talk 1 Brockwood Park, UK, 1972)" }
        );
        modelBuilder.Entity<Track>().HasData(
            new Track { Id = 1, AlbumId = 1, Name = "Chapter1" },
            new Track { Id = 2, AlbumId = 2, Name = "Chapter2" },
            new Track { Id = 3, AlbumId = 3, Name = "Chapter3" },
            new Track { Id = 4, AlbumId = 1, Name = "Chapter1" },
            new Track { Id = 5, AlbumId = 2, Name = "Chapter2" },
            new Track { Id = 6, AlbumId = 3, Name = "Chapter3" },
            new Track { Id = 7, AlbumId = 1, Name = "Chapter1" },
            new Track { Id = 8, AlbumId = 2, Name = "Chapter2" },
            new Track { Id = 9, AlbumId = 3, Name = "Chapter3" }
        );
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

This does what I expect: the data got seeded to the database, after

```
dotnet ef database update
```

But with this seed data, I created a folder in the structure as: `UploadFile/{artist.Name}/{album.DisplayName}`.

For that, I created a `BackgroundSeedingService` that inherits `BackgroundService`.and created the folder using the following code.

```
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var dBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        var artistId = 1;
        var artist = dBcontext.Artists.Where(art => art.Id == artistId).FirstOrDefault();

        string artistPath = Path.Combine($"wwwroot/UploadFile/{artist.Name}").ToLower();

        if (!Directory.Exists(artistPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(artistPath);

        var album = dBcontext.Albums.Where(art => art.ArtistId == artist.Id).ToList();

        album.ForEach(t =>
        {
            string albumPath = Path.Combine($"wwwroot/UploadFile/{artist.Name}/{t.DisplayName}").ToLower();

            //if path does not exist -> create it
            if (!Directory.Exists(albumPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(albumPath);
        });
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

This also works as I expected but the problem here is that it fetches the records from the database, and tries to create the folder every time when the application runs.

Which in my view seems as unnecessary. But I don't know whether there could be a better solution for creating the folder when the seeding is done? Is using `BackgroundService` the right way for this?

Answer (score 0):

The question is whether you need to create the folders beforehand or if it is sufficient to create them when an upload occurs. This way, you'd only have the folders that are needed.

On the other hand, if there are not too many data, ascerting that the folders exist upon startup should not be too expensive from a performance point of view. Have you measured the performance or do you want to optimize in advance?

To avoid that the folders are created each time, you'd need to store that the initialization has been done. If there are several instances of your app that each have a folder structure that the upload is stored in, I'd propose to create a marker file in the UploadFile-folder. Then you only need to check for the file and do not have to check in detail whether the folder for each album exists.

Comment: I have not measured the performance, I do want to optimize in advance.

Comment: Just try it on your local box, I'd think it should be fast enough if you do not have too many data. If it is too slow, then I'd optimize (and maybe create the folders when a file should be uploaded). If you do not need to optimize, the code is easier to maintain.

Comment: another concern is whether doing this folder creation as a background service is a proper approach?

Comment: You could also use a startup filter (https://andrewlock.net/exploring-istartupfilter-in-asp-net-core/) for running code only at startup. This should be sufficient; a background service usually contains code that runs repeatedly.